# C# Type.GetMethods() doesn't return Main() method

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm writing a reflection tool that I'll use for invoking methods from various types, and I'm testing it on simple programs.

I'm curious as why it doesn't return my `Main()` method on standard Visual Studio generated Program class

`class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { return ; }`

When I load type `Program`, and call `type.GetMethods()`; it returns 4 methods inherited from `Object` : `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType` and `Equals`.

I'm guessing `Main` is a special method as it's program's entry point, but there should be a way to retrieve its `MethodInfo`. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: @Ani: The parameterless method uses `Static | Instance | Public`

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Right. Didn't notice which overload the OP was calling. Thanks.

Comment: thanks to all of you. I've never noticed that `Main` is private, really!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Main` method is private, so you need to include `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

(`BindingFlags.Static` is included by default, but `NonPublic` isn't.)

So:

```
var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                              BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

(I'm assuming you want the public and instance methods as well, of course.)

Although `Main` is identified as the entry point here, there's nothing else that's particularly special about it - you can find it in the same way as other methods, and invoke it too.

Comment: I never know `BindingFlags.Static is included by default`, OMG. Sometimes we know something, but never try it!

Comment: @Danny: To be fair, the documentation doesn't specify exactly what binding flags are passed, which would have been helpful :(

Comment: that's when the Good Ol' Reflector comes in and saves the day :)

Answer (score 3):

`GetMethods()` returns all the **public** methods of the current Type.

You have to use `GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`

[*More info on Type.GetMethods(BindingsFlags)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Main() is private and static. Try this:

```
      MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public
                                                      | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                      | BindingFlags.Static
                                                      | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Main() is not public by default:

```
type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try using `BindingFlags.Static` when calling `GetMethods`.

Comment: It's not the static-ness which is the problem - it's the fact that it's non-public.